# Trying to build a python program that renders day of birth when user inputs birthday. Current attempt acts like a loop

Tags: python, math, date-arithmetic

We all know that in the Gregorian calendar that we are currently using, a random day of the week can be one of 7 options.

The intention of my code is based on a segment in Arthur Benjamin's Think Like A Math Genius (2006), whereby you can perform a simple party trick using mathematics. Using codes (basically implementing shortcuts based on the patterns of the Gregorian and finding the remainders after dividing by seven), one can quickly and accurately predict past and future days of the week.

My current attempt results in PyCharm overcomputing and eating up majority of CPU activity. I reckon that this could be because I have not limited the extent of user input 'Year' the same way I limited 'typedMonth'.

This is the original code:

```
print("Enter the full date: in dd/Month/yyyy")
Date = int(input("dd:"))
typedMonth = str(input("Month:"))
Year = int(input("yyyy: "))
while not int(Year) in range(0,3000):
    Year = int(input("Please enter year (yyyy) limited to [0 - 3000] : "))

if typedMonth in ['January']:
    Month = 3
    while int(Year) % 4 == 0:
        Month = 2
elif typedMonth in ['February']:
    Month = 6
    while int(Year) % 4 == 0:
        Month = 5
elif typedMonth in ['March', 'November']:
    Month = 6
elif typedMonth in ['April', 'July']:
    Month = 2
elif typedMonth in ['May']:
    Month = 4
elif typedMonth in ['August']:
    Month = 5
elif typedMonth in ['September', 'December']:
    Month = 1
elif typedMonth in ['October']:
    Month = 3
elif typedMonth in ['June']:
    Month = 0
else:
    Month = 0

remYear = Year%400

if 300 <= remYear <= 400:
    Year = Year + 1
elif 200 <= remYear <= 300:
    Year = Year + 3
elif 100 <= remYear <= 200:
    Year = Year + 5
else:
    Year = Year + 0

print(remYear)

Day = (Date + int(Month) + remYear) % 7
print(Day)
```

Isolated testing shows that the first four lines of code work as intended (if I just print `typedMonth`), for instance.

In silo, the segment near the end from `remYear= Year%400` also works as intended.

Hence, to my untrained eye, the 'overcomputation' is likely due to the stretch of code that I use to fix the Month variable from user input string `typedMonth`. To emphasise, the initial input for Month starts with the string `typedMonth`. I then use while statements to convert user input of string to an integer value. This integer value is attributed to variable 'Month' so that the final computation of integers 'Date', 'Month' and 'Year' can be made. Remainder will correspond to day of the week (e.g. 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, etc).

This is the updated code (third iteration). Thanks to the comments below, I am now able to enter most years as input and the program will run. Logic errors still persist, especially with the codes assigned to the months. I will fix them in future iterations.

```
print("Enter the full date: in dd/Month/yyyy")
Date = int(input("dd:"))
typedMonth = str(input("Month:"))
Year = int(input("yyyy: "))
while not int(Year) in range(1,3000):
    Year = int(input("Please enter year (yyyy) limited to [0 - 3000] : "))

if typedMonth in ['January']:
    Month = 3
    while int(Year) % 4 == 0:
        Month = 2
elif typedMonth in ['February']:
    Month = 6
    while int(Year) % 4 == 0:
        Month = 5
elif typedMonth in ['March', 'November']:
    Month = 6
elif typedMonth in ['April', 'July']:
    Month = 2
elif typedMonth in ['May']:
    Month = 4
elif typedMonth in ['June']:
    Month = 0
elif typedMonth in ['August']:
    Month = 5
elif typedMonth in ['September', 'December']:
    Month = 1
elif typedMonth in ['October']:
    Month = 3


remYear = Year%400

if 300 <= remYear <= 400:
    Year = Year + 1
elif 200 <= remYear <= 300:
    Year = Year + 3
elif 100 <= remYear <= 200:
    Year = Year + 5
else:
    Year = Year + 0

calcYear = int(Year % 100)

Day=(Date + Month + calcYear) % 7
print("The date is %d"%Date)
print("The month is %d"%Month)
print("The calculated year is %d"%calcYear)
print("The code for day is %d"%Day) 

if Day in [0]:
    print("You were born on a Sunday")
elif Day in [1]:
    print("You were born on a Monday")
elif Day in [2]:
    print("You were born on a Tuesday")
elif Day in [3]:
    print("You were born on a Wednesday")
elif Day in [4]:
    print("You were born on a Thursday")
elif Day in [5]:
    print("You were born on a Friday")
elif Day in [6]:
    print("You were born on a Saturday")
print("~~End Of Program~~")
```

Recommendations for restricting the range of computation of Year (limiting user input for Year does not fix the above problems) or restructuring the value for variable month from initial string input 'typedMonth' would be greatly appreciated.

P.S.1 Perhaps I should use another software for this project? I just started out with python so i don't know what applications would be more suited for such programs. Do recommend if you think that this could be a viable solution!

P.S.2 Made progress! The program kind of works for millennial babies (aka enter year after 2001), i still need to fix the logic!

P.S.3 Thanks to the comments below, I am now able to run the program. There are still glaring logic errors within the code. I endeavor to commence work on this project when time allows. I will update this post accordingly. Thanks for joining me in my learning journey!

Comment: What inputs are you using that yield and infinite loop condition? I ran your code with my own inputs and it computed as expected.

Comment: @noslenkwah Did you try a year that isn't divisible by 4?

Comment: @BenjaminPodszun - I used 14/May/1989 and it yielded 389 using Python 3.6

Comment: BTW, you could eliminate most of the month `if...elif` stuff by storing the magic numbers for the months in a dict: `{'January': 3, 'February': 6, }` Etc. Of course you still need to adjust the numbers for January & February if it's a leap year.

Comment: To be more pythonic instead using too many `if-elif-else` try to implement using `dict()`

Comment: @noslenkwah One of the problems of the original code was that if you entered a year that is divisible by 4 (```while int(Year) % 4 == 0:```) the program would go into an endless loop. 1989 is not divisible by 4...

Comment: I have rollbacked your inclusion of the solution in the question itself: instead, please post your solution (available in the revision history) in an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You asked if Python was a suitable tool for this sort of project. It is, but it is much more suitable if you use it properly. In other words, don't make the problem unnecessarily difficult.

I understand your impulse to implement a particular algorithm to get comfortable with programming, but I have to say that this isn't a good choice. Date arithmetic is usually a pain. If you want to use computational shortcuts (and you should), then take a look at the shortcuts that the Python programming environment offers.

For example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> date = "25/December/1999"
>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(parser.parse(date), "%A")
'Saturday'
```

The `dateutil` module isn't part of the standard library but it is well worth the trouble of installing.